# Microsoft Graph API I can't access my calendar (ResourceNotFound)

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

I work with a client who wants to retrieve events from an outlook calendar.

So I registered from the azure portal an application to access the API.

I manage to generate the token and also to load my user infos with urls :

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantid}/oauth2/v2.0/token (worked)
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users (worked)
```

For scope for generate my token, I use "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default".

When I want to access my calendar (the email of my azure account and the same as my outlook account) I have an error :

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_id}/calendar
```

My response :

[image]

Screen of my calendar :

[image]

From this url :

```
https://outlook.live.com/calendar/0/view/month
```

Permissions of my app are done.

[image]

To summarize, I can access my user info but my calendar seems to be non-existent. How can I make my calendar known to my application? Thanks !

Comment: Could you please include the grant_type you are using to generate access token?

Comment: Hello and thanks ! i'm using "client_credentials" for grant_type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error **`Resource not found`** usually occurs if the users don't have **active licenses** assigned to the accounts.

***I tried to reproduce the same error in my environment***

I have registered an application in Azure AD and granted below **API permissions**:

[image]

***I got the access token with same scope **`https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`** as below:***

[image]

***I'm able to access the users successfully as below:***

[image]

***I tried to access calendar for specific user who does not have any active O365 license like below:***

[image]

***I got "Resource not found" error if the user has no license like below:***

[image]

***I tried to access calendar of specific user who have active O365 licenses like below:***

[image]

***I got the response successfully like below:***

[image]

**So, make sure to have these licenses active while you are trying to get calendar of Outlook.**

If still the error persists, please check this **[Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/471424/graph-api-get-calendar-result-in-resource-not-foun.html)**

Comment: A huge thank you for taking the time to do some tests and therefore give me a solution. I still wonder if it is necessary to buy a 365 license knowing that by default we have access to our calendar when creating a Microsoft account?

Comment: AFAIK, even we have access to calendar, **[O365 licenses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/overview-licensing-activation-microsoft-365-apps#assign-and-manage-licenses)** are still required to retrieve calendar via **Postman** or any other **REST API**

Comment: I just took a 1 month trial for office 365, still can't see anything in licensing affection from azure. I think we have to wait a little longer. I'll get back to you as soon as possible. Thanks  !

Comment: @CamilleColvray Hi did you solve this problem ? This error happened to me too.